# <machineKey> for mix of x86 and x64

Tags: asp.net, configuration-files, web-farm

I have server which runs Windows 2003 (x86) and want to add windows 2008 R2, which is x64.

Is it possible to have them work as webfarm? I have issues with aspnet membership recognition between servers.

I already have **machineKey** defined at app web.config level, but this doesn't helps

Comment: Not sure what the problem might be, but we have several clients that use this configuration (using  Network Load Balancing) so it definitely will work.

Answer (score 0):

machinekey is not architecture specific - so you have something else going on I'm afraid.

Comment: I have 2 x86 instances and they are working in pair with same code.

Comment: That may be true, but honestly it's not bit specific. You can look at the code in reflector.

Comment: I end up to upgrade all servers to x64 and now it works fine. So, still somewhere there is specific. For example, GetHashCode() also give different results on x86 and x64

Answer (score 0):

The machineKey must not be autogenerate - it must be exactly the same at each server.